# How to read battery properties in RFID Scan for Zebra 8500 using Zebra_RFIDAPI3_SDK_2.0.0.2?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, rfid

I'm trying to get the battery properties from the Zebra 8500 in Rfid scan, I'm using Zebra_RFIDAPI3_SDK_2.0.0.2

what I'm trying to do is this (see the code below)

creating an RfidEventsListener  object
then subscribing to eventStatusNotify and trying to access the battery charging, level

But each time it gives me values as null seems there is some issue with  the RfidEventsListener.

Can some one assist me on this ?

```
        rfidReader.Events.setBatteryEvent(true);
        rfidReader.Config.getDeviceStatus(true, true, true);
        StatusEventData statusEventData = 
       rfidReader.Events.GetStatusEventData(RFID_EVENT_TYPE.BATTERY_EVENT);
        RfidStatusEvents rfidReadEvents = new RfidStatusEvents(statusEventData);
        rfidReadEvents.setStatusEventData(statusEventData);
        rfidReader.Events.addEventsListener(eventHandler);
        eventHandler.eventStatusNotify(rfidStatusEvents);

        RfidEventsListener eventHandler = new RfidEventsListener() {


            @Override
            public void eventStatusNotify(RfidStatusEvents rfidStatusEvents) {
                    boolean charging = rfidStatusEvents.StatusEventData.BatteryData.getCharging();
                    int battery = rfidStatusEvents.StatusEventData.BatteryData.getLevel();
                    String batterycause = rfidStatusEvents.StatusEventData.BatteryData.getCause();
                    StatusEventData statusEventData = rfidReader.Events.GetStatusEventData(RFID_EVENT_TYPE.BATTERY_EVENT);
                    RfidStatusEvents rfidReadEvents = new RfidStatusEvents(statusEventData);
                    rfidReadEvents.setStatusEventData(statusEventData);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void eventReadNotify(RfidReadEvents rfidReadEvents) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "rfidReadEvents : ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
```

Comment: I have the same problem, the RfidEventsListener works when the Zebra is on the charger. If I take it off, it will not work. Very strange

Comment: I have it working. If you still need some help let me know

Comment: Hi @Gregga17 Yes please, can you also help me with Async tag reads as well.

Comment: It is very much to post, send me a message on linkedin via chat or have you any other idea, then I can explain better. https://www.linkedin.com/in/gregory-lammers-6b710987/

Comment: will catch up with you on LinkedIn. Thanks :)

Comment: I've completed an application for the Zebra RFID in android & iOS with the following functionalities :
Connect, Is Connected, Disconnect, Get Device Info, Scan RFIDS(Sync), Search(Sync), Set Output Power, Subscribe (Async), Unsubscribe(Async), Start Search(Async), Stop Search(Async)
I can help If required, don't hesitate to contact :) Cheers :)